# Python output help, making a frequency list reading in from another file

Tags: python

So I know how to extract the words I need from the file, but what I don't quite understand is how to integrate a loop counting the frequency of my extracted words. Here's what I have:

```
myfile = open('sample.pos')
file = open('sample.sorted', 'w')
line = myfile.readline()
list =[]

while line:
     line = myfile.readline()
     line.strip()
     if len(line) > 1:
         list.append(line)
list.sort()

x=0
while x < len(list):

     ll=list[x].split()
     file.write(ll[1] + '\n')
     x = x +1

myfile.close()
file.close()
```

I wanted to take my first list and using a loop count my word frequencies using something like this.

```
list = []  
list2 = []    

for word in list:
     if word in list2:
         list2.index(word)[1] += 1
else:
    list2.append([word,0])
```

I'm just incredibly stuck in how to integrate this with the file.write and my current code. The end result is to have each word listed on a separate line with its frequency.  What I get currently is just a list.

Comment: What is your list holding, if it is `[word, frequency_of_the_word]`, you have the line `if word in list2` wrong. You might want to consider [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) for saving key,value pairs. Look at [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) too.

Answer (score 0):

```
myfile = open('sample.pos')
file = open('sample.sorted', 'w')
list =[]

for line in myfile:
  line.strip()
  if len(line) > 1:
    list.append(line)

list2 = []    

for word in list:
  if word in [x for x in list2[0]]:
     list2.index(word)[1] += 1
else:
  list2.append([word,0])
```

but using dict would probably be better

```
wordCount = {}
for word in list:
  if word in wordCount.keys():
    wordCount[word] += 1
  else:
    wordcount[word] = 0
```

then you can access any word's count by `wordCount[word]`